# Why use Axios when using React and not just Node HTTPS module?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, mern

This might be a trivial question, but I am new to the MERN stack.

At the moment I am somewhat decent with React/Express individually and I am trying to connect both worlds.

I was looking through the web to see how to do this and more often than not I found people using `Axios` to make API calls, and my question is, why don't we just use the HTTPS module in node to make those calls (if it was not our own API of course) and if it were our own API, why don't we just call it directly, for example if we have a form:

```
return(
<form action="localhost:3000/exampleRoute" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="upvote" value="Upvote" />
</form>);
```

And that would make a post request to my local host given that it runs on port 3000?

Comment: 1. Because you're not running that React code in a Node environment, it runs in your users' browsers; and 2. you can still use forms in React if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

[react](https://reactjs.org/) is a framework to write client-side\frontend applications.

the result of "building" the react project, is a set of files that needs to be served (using http(s)) to clients (browsers).

node provide standard libraries which are not part of ecmascript specifications. on the other hand, browsers implement only the ecmascript specification. thus, node standard libraries are not available in the browser.

this is the reason that there is a "build" for the react project, to produce a javascript that will be able to run withn the browser.

the build process is basically a [traspilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler).